# Document Library level Read-Only group can still edit document

Tags: document-library, permissions

I have a word document in a document library. I created a group that has read only access to this document library.

I logon as a user in this group and am able to open the document. I am unable to edit at this moment, but the at the top it says this document was opened from a server in read only mode. This is what I need, but there's also a button that says "Edit Document". This defeats the purpose of being a restricted reader. If I click on this button I can edit.

Is this a bug? Can I get around this?

Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 2):

When you say you logged in as a different user, did you just use the browser, or did you login to windows as the new user. If you just use the broswer, MS office has probably opened the document as the user that you are logged into windows as.

Answer (score 1):

Log into the computer as that person and then try.  Also check to make sure that that user is not part of an owners group or is listed as a site collection administrator.  At the web application level, we're groups of people given permissions?

Comment: You guys are lifesavers. I was loggin into windows with my account, but logging into sharepoint with the test user account. I logged out of Windows and logged back in with the test user account and all worked as expected. I was not allowed to save any changes to the document back to the document library. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will allow them to edit the document, but won't allow them to save it back to the SharePoint document library...It happens to all read-only mode users.

Answer (score 0):

As your Admin/Content author account, in the document library, click on Library Permissions, then Check Permissions and enter the user that you want to confirm permissions for. this will show exactly what permissions that user has on that library.

If it is Read only, then it's as Mike stated, you can open the file and edit it, but not save it back to the same library.

If you really want to stop them doing anything with the document like edit/print etc, then you'll need to start looking at Rights Management Services.

Paul.